# JQuery - $('#test ul > li').index(2).hide(); - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, html-lists

Can I work with the index value so easily? I think using the natural index values is better then using classes. I want to use the .index in that way.

Html

```
<div id="test">
<ul>
<li>Im index 0</li>
<li>Im index 1</li>
<li>Im index 2</li>
<li>Im index 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Pseudo (Jquery) Javascript

```
$('#test ul > li').index(2).hide();

$('#test ul > li').index(1).click(function() {
 alert('lulz you clicked the li with the index value of 1 bro');
});
```

I doesnt find a clue how to work this way with the .index value.. is it possible to work that easily with this method??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('#test ul > li').eq(2).hide();
```

It can also be a part of your selector:

```
$('#test ul > li:eq(2)').hide();
```

If you want the third `li` in all `ul`s in `#test`, you can use [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) (note it is 1-based):

```
$('#test ul > li:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. You want `.eq()` however, instead of `.index()`:

```
$('#test ul > li').eq(2).hide();
```

Or as part of the selector:

```
$('#test ul > li:eq(2)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using it with an integer (number), but you can only use it with a selector or element. [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Edit:
You could write your own function like this:

```
function indexValue(index)
{
    $(element).each(function(key, val) {
        if(key+1 == index) // + 1 because you started from 0
        {
            return val;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button#1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button#2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
<button id="1">Clica-me</button>
<button id="2">Volta-me</button>
```